# As3 - what "src" stands for in action script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Could you please tell me what does "**@src**" stands for in action script 3 ? For example in this bit of code:

```
var videoURL = this.videoInfo.@src.toString();
            if (videoURL && videoURL != "") {
                this.videoView.load(videoURL);
            }
```

I couldn't find it on a google ;).

Comment: "src" is a local name of an XML parameter, it is not a general question about AS3

Comment: They had no way to know that without asking (if you don't know already, how would you know where to look). I'm upvoting because I don't agree that downvoting was fair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the bit of the code provided - it looks that src is an attribute in a XML tag that has the path/filename of the video. Are the videos loaded from XML application from which the above code is pasted?

Comment: "Are the videos loaded from XML application from which the above code is pasted?" - yes. But what about "@" in "@src" ?

Comment: @ is an attribute identifier operator - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#attribute_identifier - this might help you

Answer (score 2):

`src` stands for "source". I believe the `@` sign just means that `src` is an attribute of `videoInfo`.